# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis tips in Order by

Tags: sql, oracle

missing right parenthesis tips in Order by !!

i want to get last  amn_unit_pric_rial from sal_sale_fct
per  shp.DAT_CALCULATE, shp.COD_PROD_SAPRB
from shp_inventory_fct
if  row is not found in sal_sale_fct
return a last price from  last date in sal_sale_fct

```
select shp.DAT_CALCULATE,
      shp.COD_PROD_SAPRB,     
          (select sal.amn_unit_pric_rial
                  from sal_sale_fct sal 
                 where rownum = 1
                   and shp.cod_prod_saprb = sal.saprb_cod_prod_saprb
                   and shp.dat_calculate <= sal.dat_ord_ordhe
                   order by sal.dat_ord_ordhe
                   ) price
  From shp_inventory_fct shp
```

Comment: Please explain " if row is not found in sal_sale_fct return a last price from last date in sal_sale_fct" as it doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you should post some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 7):

When you use rownum and order by together then the rownum is evaluated first .Hence the first row will not be in the order by of sal.dat_ord_ordhe. So you need to order by first and then select the first row using rownum

```
select shp.DAT_CALCULATE,
  shp.COD_PROD_SAPRB,     
      (select price 
           From  (
             select sal.amn_unit_pric_rial price
              from sal_sale_fct sal 
             where shp.cod_prod_saprb = sal.saprb_cod_prod_saprb
               and shp.dat_calculate <= sal.dat_ord_ordhe
               order by sal.dat_ord_ordhe
               ) where  rownum = 1) Price
               From shp_inventory_fct shp
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't use a `ORDER BY` clause in a nested subquery. Try changing your query to something like

```
select shp.DAT_CALCULATE,
      shp.COD_PROD_SAPRB,     
 sal.amn_unit_pric_rial
 from shp_inventory_fct shp 
 join sal_sale_fct sal 
 on shp.cod_prod_saprb = sal.saprb_cod_prod_saprb
 and shp.dat_calculate <= sal.dat_ord_ordhe
 order by sal.dat_ord_ordhe;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason for this error, but I don't think that this will work, even if you fix the error. I guess you want the row with the closest `dat_ord_ordhe` after `shp.dat_calculate`. The `ORDER BY` will takes place after the result is filtered by the `WHERE` clause, so your `rownum = 1` will select any row but not the one you want.

Maybe this will help (but is untested):

```
SELECT dat_calculate,
       cod_prod_saprb,
       amn_unit_pric_rial
  FROM(SELECT shp.dat_calculate,
              shp.cod_prod_saprb,
              sal.amn_unit_pric_rial,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shp.dat_calculate, shp.cod_prod_saprb
                                     ORDER BY sal.dat_ord_ordhe) AS rank
         FROM shp_inventory_fct shp
         JOIN sal_sale_fct sal 
           ON shp.cod_prod_saprb = sal.saprb_cod_prod_saprb
          AND shp.dat_calculate <= sal.dat_ord_ordhe
      )
 WHERE rank = 1
```

Comment: number of returned  rows is not equal with table shp_inventory_fct --i want to get last amn_unit_pric_rial from sal_sale_fct per shp.DAT_CALCULATE, shp.COD_PROD_SAPRB from shp_inventory_fct if row is not found in sal_sale_fct return a last price from last date in sal_sale_fct

Comment: Then use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN` and handle NULL values for `amn_unit_pric_rial` properly

Answer (score 0):

No sense there in `order by` anyway because even if your query would work, it would just order the one row returning due to your `rownum = 1`. If you want the record with max dat_ord_ordhe your subquery should look like this:

```
select shp.DAT_CALCULATE,
      shp.COD_PROD_SAPRB, 
   ( select sal.amn_unit_pric_rial
      from sal_sale_fct sal 
      where shp.cod_prod_saprb = sal.saprb_cod_prod_saprb
        and shp.dat_calculate <= sal.dat_ord_ordhe
        and rownum = 1
        and sal.dat_ord_ordhe = ( select max ( sal.dat_ord_ordhe )   
                                    from sal_sale_fct sal 
                                   where shp.cod_prod_saprb = sal.saprb_cod_prod_saprb
                                     and shp.dat_calculate <= sal.dat_ord_ordhe) ) price
From shp_inventory_fct shp
```

Comment: So you have multiple entries for `max ( sal.dat_ord_ordhe  )`. Added rownum = 1 above, ora-1427 should be gone, wich means it should return whatever your query in the question should return, though I don't understand the aim.

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-00907` almost always indicates a syntax error.  It means Oracle has encountered a keyword or something else when it was expecting a parenthesis.  In this case it is the ORDER BY clause it doesn't like.

The reason for the error is that a scalar subquery must return only one row.  (You obviously know this, that's why you have `rownum=1`).  If a result set has only one row there's no point in sorting it, so Oracle throws any error.

Now you think there is a reason for sorting, because you want the subquery to return the most recent value of `amn_unit_pric_rial`.  Your code won't do this because that's not how ROWNUM() works.  ROWNUM() applies the STOP COUNT operation as soon as the query has fetched that number of rows; then any sort is applied.  So `rownum=1` means your subquery will just return one essentially random value of `amn_unit_pric_rial`.

There are various ways of solving this problem, but using a subquery with the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function is quite elegant, and should perform well under most circumstances.

```
with cte as 
   (
        select shp.dat_calculate
               , shp.cod_prod_saprb
               , sal.amn_unit_pric_rial
               , row_number() over (order by dat_ord_ordhe desc) rn
        from   shp_inventory_fct shp
               , sal_sale_fct sal 
        where shp.cod_prod_saprb = sal.saprb_cod_prod_saprb
        and shp.dat_calculate <= sal.dat_ord_ordhe
)
select dat_calculate
       , cod_prod_saprb
       , amn_unit_pric_rial as price
from cte
where  rn = 1                 
/
```

Using ROW_NUMBER will guarantee you get only one result, even if you have several `sal_sale_fct` records with same value of `dat_ord_ordhe`.